# Solve SelectBox inside Scrollview Warning?

Tags: java, react-native, scrollview

I'm using the Multi-SelectBox from "react-native-multi-selectbox" inside a KeyboardAwareScrollView from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view" and get the commom known warning of: "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation-...".

Simplified code:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
   
   //Text, Inputs

   <SelectBox />

   //Texts, Inputs, Buttons

</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

It seems to be working just fine, can't notice any weird behaviour. Also the warning just appears, when I open the Dropdown menu from the SelectBox. Can I ignore this warning and if not, how can I solve it?